# how to pass pameters with brackets to restemplate

Tags: java, resttemplate

I am connecting to a third party tool that uses brackets inside their url parameters.  I'm proxying someone else parameters, so I'm not building these parameters up and don't want to have to parse them exactly.

I've tried a basic encoding of parameters, this fails due to the third party application not knowing how to parse the encoding, it tries to read the encoded values directly as far as I can tell.

I realize this is not exactly how resttemplate is designed to work, but everywhere else in our code uses restTemplate and I don't want to bring in a new service simply for a basic proxy.

Is there any way to make resttemplate allow the brackets through without trying to do substitution on them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use escape URL codes for special characters in the URL. e.g. If your URL is `http://domainURL/{url-part}/rest-of-the-url` then you could refer to it as `http://domainURL/%7Burl-part%7D/rest-of-the-url`.

Below is the code snippet for the reference:

```
    LoginDetails loginDetails = restTemplate.getForObject(restServiceURL +
 "%7Btest-paranthesis%7D/" + userUUID, LoginDetails.class);
```

For the above code the URL is `http://localhost:8087/userLogin{test-paranthesis}/842063819010`